# How to use a "images" group to store iphone app images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I would like to use a group called "images" I created from xcode project left navigator. I intend to store icons, logos, buttons, and other pictures I use to make up the app. Is there any special config I need ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: just drag and drop the images in that folder.. I don't think there is anything else you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to do anything. Just create the group an add the images to it.